# Text Processing - Word2Vec training after phrase detection (bigram model)

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, text-processing

I want to make a word2vec model with more n-grams that usual. As I found, Phrase class in gensim.models.phrase can find phrases that I want and it's possible to use phrases on corpus and use it's result model for word2vec train function.

So first of all I do something like below, exactly like sample codes in [gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield word_tokenize(line)

sentences = MySentences('sentences_directory')

bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(sentences)

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(bigram['sentences'], size=300, window=5, workers=8)
```

model has been created but without any good result in evaluation and a warning :

```
WARNING : train() called with an empty iterator (if not intended, be sure to provide a corpus that offers restartable iteration = an iterable)
```

I searched for it and I found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/XWQ8fPMFSi0 and changed my code:

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield word_tokenize(line)

class PhraseItertor(object):
    def __init__(self, my_phraser, data):
        self.my_phraser, self.data = my_phraser, data

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.my_phraser[self.data]


sentences = MySentences('sentences_directory')

bigram_transformer = gensim.models.Phrases(sentences)

bigram = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram_transformer)

corpus = PhraseItertor(bigram, sentences)

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(corpus, size=300, window=5, workers=8)
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fatemeh/Desktop/Thesis/bigramModeler.py", line 36, in <module>
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(corpus, size=300, window=5, workers=8)
  File "/home/fatemeh/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 478, in init
    self.build_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)
  File "/home/fatemeh/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 553, in build_vocab
    self.scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)  # initial survey
  File "/home/fatemeh/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 575, in scan_vocab
    vocab[word] += 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Now I want to know that what is wrong in my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my question in [Gensim GoogleGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/hJ216c59TGM) and [Mr Gordon Mohr](https://www.linkedin.com/in/gojomo) answered me:

> You typically wouldn't want an `__iter__()` method to do a single
>   `yield`. It should return an iterator object (ready to return multiple
>   objects via `next()` or a StopIteration exception). One way to effect
>   a iterator is to use `yield` to have the method treated as a
>   'generator' – but that would typically require the `yield` to be
>   inside a loop.
>
> But I now see that my example code in the thread you reference does
>   the wrong thing with *its* `__iter__()` return line: it should not be
>   returning the raw phrasifier, but one that has already been
>   started-as-an-iterator, by use of the `iter()` built-in method. That
>   is, the example there should have read:
>
> ```
> class PhrasingIterable(object):
>     def __init__(self, phrasifier, texts):
>         self. phrasifier, self.texts = phrasifier, texts
>     def __iter__():
>         return iter(phrasifier[texts])
> ```
>
> Making a similar change in your variation may resolve the `TypeError:
>   iter() returned non-iterator of type 'TransformedCorpus'` error.